# How do I load a Vue3 project into WebView for .net Maui Android

Tags: android, vuejs3, vite, maui

I'm currently trying to load a build from a Vue3 project using Vite into a WebView in .net Maui Android.

I've tried this:

```
            <WebView>
                <WebView.Source>
                    <HtmlWebViewSource>
                        <HtmlWebViewSource.Html>
                            <![CDATA[
                <html>
                <head>
                </head>
                <body>
                <p><a href="indexifc.html">next page</a></p>
                </body>
                </html>                    
                ]]>
                        </HtmlWebViewSource.Html>
                    </HtmlWebViewSource>
                </WebView.Source>
            </WebView>
```

And then including the html file in the "Raw" folder as a MAUIAsset.

This isn't really what we want as it doesn't load the rest of the Vue3 Build. So this doesn't work.

Comment: MAUI is compatible with Blazor. If you want web site, you use it. Everything else will require continuous effort to keep it running. (To be honest, even Blazor, that is supported, requires decent effort.

Comment: You want to use `BlazorWebView` rather than `WebView`. But don't try to add a BlazorWebView element to your existing project; start a `New Project` using `Maui Blazor` Project Template.